# Python dataframe iterate and assign unique value for each duplicate

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I'm trying to create a script which removes all rows which have a matching negative and positive unique ID totaling to nil.

Is there are function/ module that could easily and efficiently achieve this goal without having to go about the `df.iterrows` route?

Original Dataset extract (full dataset has lots of different references and amounts)

| reference | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 5231 | 505 |
| 5231 | -505 |
| 5231 | 505 |
| 5231 | -505 |
| 5231 | -505 |
| 5231 | 505 |
| 5231 | 505 |
| 5231 | 505 |

I have created the ID column, however need to create a `"Unique_ID_Count"` column to identify the number of duplicates.

| reference | amount | ID | Unique_ID_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5231 | 505 | 5231_505 | 5231_505_0 |
| 5231 | -505 | 5231_-505 | 5231_-505_0 |
| 5231 | 505 | 5231_505 | 5231_505_1 |
| 5231 | -505 | 5231_-505 | 5231_-505_1 |
| 5231 | -505 | 5231_-505 | 5231_-505_2 |
| 5231 | 505 | 5231_505 | 5231_505_2 |
| 5231 | 505 | 5231_505 | 5231_505_3 |
| 5231 | 505 | 5231_505 | 5231_505_4 |

Once I've identified my duplicates I need to remove all instances where there is a corresponding positive and negative duplicate with the same count. This removes all rows that net off to nil.

| reference | amount | ID | Unique_ID_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5231 | 505 | 5231_505 | 5231_505_3 |
| 5231 | 505 | 5231_505 | 5231_505_4 |

Any help would be much appreciated as I feel like I'm going in circles thinking about how to achieve this.

Data:

```
{'reference': [5231, 5231, 5231, 5231, 5231, 5231, 5231, 5231],
 'amount': [505, -505, 505, -505, -505, 505, 505, 505]}
```

Comment: do you need to create the 'ID' and unique_ID columns, or are those there just to help you get to your goal?

Comment: And, is your goal just to be left with the rows that a reference does not total to 0? For example the desired output should be a dataframe with reference = 5231, and amount = 505?

Comment: The ID and unique_ID are there to help me get to my goal. Yes the desired output is the last table, however I would also like to transfer the removed rows into a separate dataframe. @sophocles

Comment: Could the matching rows be all over the place? The structure of your example looks pretty "benign", i.e. matching rows occur consecutively, only one reference, etc. I assume that's not necessarily the case in your original data? And are there additional columns that have to be preserved?

Answer (score 2):

Something this will help you out

```
cols = ['reference','amount']
df["ID"] = df[cols].apply(lambda row: '_'.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)   
df["Unique_ID_Count"] = df.groupby(["ID"]).cumcount()+1
df["Unique_ID_Count"] = df["key"] + '_' + df["Unique_ID_Count"]
```

Answer (score 2):

What if you `groupby` your 'reference' column and `sum` your 'amount' column. This will filter out naturally the rows that are nil:

```
res = df.groupby('reference',as_index=False)['amount'].sum()

print(res)
   reference  amount
0       5231     505
```

Then you can drop from your main data frame `res`'s index rows:

```
other_rows = df.loc[~df.index.isin(res.index.tolist())]

print(other_rows)

  reference  amount
1       5231    -505
2       5231     505
3       5231    -505
4       5231    -505
5       5231     505
6       5231     505
```

Comment: Thanks @sophocles, I'm not sure if this will work for example if there were two more rows in the original data set with reference 5231 and amount 505 I would want it to return a dataframe with 3 rows all with reference 5231 and amount 505 as there are no -505 amounts to net against it. Hope this makes sense, appreciate this wasn't clear from the offset.

Comment: I've changed the table in my original table to include one additional row which I think would change the outcome of the above and hopefully make the desired output a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

A bit convoluted, but I guess it would work: I'd use the index instead of creating unique IDs.

I created a dataframe with another reference value, for which the amount will total to a negative value, just in case that would happen in your data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'amount': [505, -505, 505, -505, -505, 505, 505, 505]}
)
df['reference'] = 5231
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'amount': [505, -505, 505, -505, -505, 505, -505, -505]}
)
df2['reference'] = 6451

df = pd.concat([df, df2]).sort_values(by=['reference', 'amount']).reset_index(drop=True)

grouped = df.groupby('reference', as_index=False)
keep = []
for i, grp in grouped:
    pos_idx = grp.loc[grp.amount>0].index
    neg_idx = grp.loc[grp.amount<0].index
    gap = len(pos_idx) - len(neg_idx)
    if gap > 0:
        keep.extend(pos_idx[:gap])
    elif gap < 0:
        idx_to_keep = neg_idx[:abs(gap)].values.tolist()
        keep.extend(idx_to_keep)
df[df.index.isin(keep)]
```

|  | amount | reference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 505 | 5231 |
| 4 | 505 | 5231 |
| 8 | -505 | 6451 |
| 9 | -505 | 6451 |

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative:

```
df["amnt_abs"] = df.amount.abs()
df2 = df.groupby(["reference", "amnt_abs"], as_index=False).sum()
df2["num_rows"] = df2.amount.abs() // df2.amnt_abs 
df2.amount /= df2.num_rows
df2 = df2.loc[df2.index.repeat(df2.num_rows), ["reference", "amount"]]
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

With the sample DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "reference": [5231] * 8 + [5232] * 4,
    "amount": [505, -505] * 3 + [505, 505] + [-10, -10, 1, -1]
})
```

this

```
df["amnt_abs"] = df.amount.abs()
df2 = df.groupby(["reference", "amnt_abs"], as_index=False).sum()
```

does produce

```
   reference  amnt_abs  amount
0       5231       505    1010
1       5232         1       0
2       5232        10     -20
```

and therefore this

```
df2["num_rows"] = df2.amount.abs() // df2.amnt_abs 
df2.amount /= df2.num_rows
```

results in

```
   reference  amnt_abs  amount  num_rows
0       5231       505   505.0         2
1       5232         1     NaN         0
2       5232        10   -10.0         2
```

Now [`index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) can produce the right number of rows: This

```
df2 = df2.loc[df2.index.repeat(df2.num_rows), ["reference", "amount"]]
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
```

results in

```
   reference  amount
0       5231   505.0
1       5231   505.0
2       5232   -10.0
3       5232   -10.0
```

But: This won't work if an `amount` is `0`. Is this allowed?

Answer (score 0):

For a given absolute amount (we'll handle reference later), you can create a function to net out positive and negative rows like

```
def net(df):
    if (df["amount"] == 0).any():
        return df
    df = df.sort_values(by="amount").reset_index(drop=True)
    num_pos = (df["amount"] > 0).astype(int).sum()
    num_neg = len(df) - num_pos
    diff = num_pos - num_neg
    if diff > 0:
        return df.tail(diff)

    if diff < 0:
        return df.head(abs(diff))

    return pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
```

Then group your data frame by absolute amount and reference, and apply the `net` function to each group:

```
def main(df):
    df["abs_amt"] = df["amount"].abs()
    xform = df.groupby(["reference", "abs_amt"], as_index=False).apply(net)
    xform = xform.drop("abs_amt", axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
    return xform
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem which can be vectorised with a subtle use of sorting.

Start with this dataset:

```py
df = DataFrame(
    [
        # Two more `1` than `-1`
        ("a", 1), ("a", -1), ("a", 1),
        ("a", -1), ("a", -1), ("a", 1),
        ("a", 1), ("a", 1),
        # Three more `-2` than 2
        ("b", -2), ("b", -2), ("b", 2),
        ("b", 2), ("b", -2), ("b", -2),
        ("b", 2), ("b", -2), ("b", -2),
    ],
    columns=("reference", "amount"),
)
```

We sort the DataFrame by the `amount` column, first ascending, then descending, and finally remove any rows where the different sorts don't match.

To see why this works, take a simple example:

```py
>>> simple_example = [-1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> DataFrame({"asc": sorted(simple_example), "desc": reversed(sorted(simple_example))})
   asc  desc
0   -1     1
1   -1     1
2    1     1  # <- These rows have no partner "-1" row
3    1     1  # <- and are hence not cancelled out
4    1    -1
5    1    -1
```

Here's one possible implementation of such an algorithm:

```py
sort_args = {"by": ["reference", "amount"], "ignore_index": True}

asc_and_desc = concat(
    (
        df.sort_values(ascending=(True, True), **sort_args),
        df.sort_values(ascending=(True, False), **sort_args),
    ),
    axis=1,
    keys=("original", "inverse"),
)

result = asc_and_desc[
    asc_and_desc["original"]["amount"] == asc_and_desc["inverse"]["amount"]
]["original"]
```

This results in the expected output, with all inverse rows cancelled out:

```py
>>> result
  reference  amount
0         a       1
1         a       1
2         b      -2
3         b      -2
4         b      -2
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing missing from your solution is a `drop_duplicates` on the subset of reference and count.
The ID column wouldn't be necessary, but I kept it for clarity.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'reference': [5231, 5231, 5231, 5231, 5231, 5231, 5231, 5231], 
                   'amount': [505, -505, 505, -505, -505, 505, 505, 505]})

df['ID'] = df['reference'].astype(str)+'_'+df['amount'].astype(str)
df['count'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount()
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['reference', 'count'], keep=False)
```

OUTPUT

```
reference   amount  ID  count
6   5231    505 5231_505    3
7   5231    505 5231_505    4
```

Answer (score 0):

So you'd like to remove 2 rows only when they have a matching but opposite value, and the same reference -- while keeping any number of excess rows, negative or positive?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'reference': [5231, 5231, 5231, 5231, 5231, 5231, 5231, 5231, 1, 1, 1],
                   'amount': [505, -505, 505, -505, -505, 505, 505, 505, 1, -1, 1]
                   })

# group rows with same amount and reference (rename columnn to avoid using the size function)
grouped = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(),as_index=False).size()
grouped.rename(columns={'size': 'counts'}, inplace=True)
```

The result of grouping and counting rows:

| idx | reference | amount | counts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | -1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 5231 | -505 | 3 |
| 3 | 5231 | 505 | 5 |

```
# keep track of negative indices
grouped['counts'] = grouped.counts.mask(grouped.amount < 0, -grouped.counts)
# absolute values
grouped['amount'] = grouped.amount.mask(grouped.amount < 0, -grouped.amount)
# rows with same ref and amount should be subtracted
grouped['subtract'] = grouped.duplicated(subset=['reference', 'amount'])
# the amount to be subtracted can be found by shifting the counts index
grouped['shifted'] = grouped.counts.shift().fillna(0)
# number of rows to keep (based on subtract booleans)
grouped['num_rows_to_keep'] = grouped.apply(lambda x: x.counts + int(x.shifted) if x.subtract else x.counts, 
                                            axis=1)
```

Result of collecting additional information on rows to keep/remove:

| idx | reference | amount | counts | subtract | shifted | num_rows_to_keep |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | -1 | False | 0.0 | -1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | True | -1.0 | 1 |
| 2 | 5231 | 505 | -3 | False | 2.0 | -1 |
| 3 | 5231 | 505 | 5 | True | -3.0 | 2 |

```
nested_list = grouped.apply(lambda x: [{'reference': x['reference'], 'amount': x['amount']}] * x.num_rows_to_keep if x.subtract else [], axis=1).to_list()
pd.DataFrame(list(chain.from_iterable(nested_list)))
```

What I believe to be your desired result, without using iterrows():

| idx | reference | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 5231 | 505 |
| 2 | 5231 | 505 |